# Why does this C program print an output of -1?

Tags: c

I was taking a practice programming quiz, and I'm not sure why this program prints out -1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1;

    if (x-- && x-- && x--)
    {
        printf("%d\n", x);
    } else
    {
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint:  1. What is *short circuiting* ? and 2. what does `x--` specifically do that is different from `--x`?

Comment: x-- does assignment then decrement, --x does decrement then assignment.

Comment: @Cascara `s/assignment/yield result/g`. there's no assignment in there.

Answer (score 7):

In C, logical operators such as `&&` and `||` are evaluated using [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), which essentially means that when a statement is guaranteed to be either true or false, any subsequent expressions in the statement are not evaluated.

In your program, only the first two conditions need to be evaluated to determine that the whole statement is false. The third expression is not evaluated.

```
if (x-- &&   /* evaluates true, and then x is decremented */
    x-- &&   /* evaluates false, and then x is decremented */
    x--)     /* this is not executed */
```

Because this is a series of `AND` statements, logically, only one expression needs to be false for the whole statement to be false. When the second expression is determined to be false, there's no need to waste resources by evaluating the rest of the statement, so the `else` block is executed.

This causes the final value of `x` to be `-1`, instead of `-2`.

Comment: So when an "if statement" has many conditions, this means: the FIRST TRUE condition is acted upon, and the FIRST FALSE condition can outweigh all previous true conditions. Is this logical to conclude from your response?

Comment: @Cascara I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "acted upon", but with short-circuit evaluation, if an `if` statement is composed of all `&&` operations (like yours is), then evaluation stops after the first occurrence of `false`. Because, logically, there's no reason to continue.

Comment: Thanks.  By "acted upon" I mean if the output (attached to the true portion of the "if statement") will execute. Does that help?

Comment: it's not the if statement that is evaluated using short-circuiting. it's the `&&` and `||` logical operators.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant That's true. You can use `&&` and `||` outside the context of an `if` statement, and short-circuit evaluation would still come into play. I clarified the answer.

Comment: @Cascara I'm still not entirely clear on what you're trying to say, but when there are multiple conditions in an `if` statement joined by `&&`, I suppose one could say that a false condition can "outweigh all previous true conditions". You just have to understand what the `&&` operation does, and then it's easy to understand why you don't need to continue evaluating when you determine that the first part of the expression is false.

Answer (score 2):

First start with `x = 1`, then the sequence of `x-- && x-- && x--` goes like this, where each `x--` represents the respective part of the condition.. (note that `&&` acts as a sequence point).

```
x = 1   ->    x = 1

x--     -> 1, x = 0
```

The result is 1 (`1 && x-- && x--`) so right-hand express of the first `&&` is evaluated.

```
x--     -> 0, x = -1
```

The result is 0 (`1 && 0 && x--`) and the && short-circuit evaluation kicks in and the right-hand expression of the second && is *not* evaluated.

```
x--
```

Nope; as above this was not evaluated.

Since the condition is false `(1 && 0 && dont_care_not_evaluated)` it prints out the value, in the `else` case, while having *only* decremented x twice.

Answer (score 2):

In C language, the test statement would end its operation as soon as the result can be determined. In this case, the first `x--` returns 1 and set x = 0, the second `x--` returns 0 and set x = -1.

1 && 0 can determine the result as 0, so the last `x--` is ignored.

With a FALSE statement, the `if-else` choose the second `printf` as output and print the value of `x` : -1;

Comment: what's a "false statement"?

Answer (score 0):

1. x-- -> 1-- it returns 1 here, after it gets decrements to 0
2. x-- -> 0-- it returns 0 here, what means false, after it gets decremented x to
3. x-- -> its unreahched, because this is an and condition, it stops if a part of it is false

so the final value will be -1 (what is not 0, so -1 is interpreted as true)